# R web-scraping multiple elements from sub-pages of a website

Tags: r, web-scraping

That has been an one on a million shot but I have found here a chunk of code I need to parse data from **pubmed** website ([R Web scraping data from links included in subpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75231542/r-web-scraping-data-from-links-included-in-subpages)).  In order to have a quick overview, I copy and paste the code here.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

   page <- "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=((((((%E2%80%98Food%20Supply%E2%80%99%20(MeSH))%20OR%20%E2%80%98Food%20Storage%E2%80%99%20(MeSH))%20OR%20%E2%80%98Hunger%E2%80%99(MeSH)%20OR%20food%20security%20OR%20food%20insecurity%20OR%20household%20food%20security%20OR%20global%20food%20security)%20OR%20household%20food%20insecurity)))%20AND%20((%E2%80%98Prevalence%E2%80%99%20(MeSH))%20OR%20%E2%80%98Cross-Sectional%20Studies%E2%80%99%20(MeSH)%20OR%20cross-sectional%20study%20OR%20Prevalence%20Studies%20OR%20prevalence%20study%20OR%20Cross-Sectional%20Analyses%20OR%20CrossSectional%20Analysis%20OR%20Cross%20Sectional%20Analysis%20OR%20Cross%20Sectional%20Analyses)&filter=lang.english&filter=lang.portuguese" %>% 
    read_html()

   df <- page %>% 
    html_elements(".docsum-content") %>% 
    map_dfr(~ tibble(
   title = .x %>% 
    html_element(".docsum-title") %>% 
    html_text2(), 
  authors = .x %>% 
   html_element(".full-authors") %>% 
   html_text2(), 
 PMID = .x %>% 
  html_element(".docsum-pmid") %>% 
  html_text2(), 
synopsis = .x %>% 
  html_element(".full-view-snippet") %>% 
  html_text2(), 
 link = .x %>% 
  html_element(".docsum-title") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  str_c("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov", .)
 ))

get_abstract <- function(link) {
 cat("Scraping:", link, "\n")
 link %>%
 read_html() %>%
 html_elements(".abstract-content.selected") %>%
 html_text2()
}

df %>% 
 mutate(
 abstract = map_chr(link, get_abstract)
 )
```

The structure here is quite simple: page() includes the extraction of data from the main pages and get_abstract() the extraction of data from sub-pages. In order to repeat the operation over and over again, the coders have prepared a function.
My problem is that I would like to parse other data from the subpages, such as 'DOI', 'cited by', etc.
I have tried to replicate with get_doi() etc. but it does not work out. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Heres some functions to extract them

```
sample_link = "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33481662/"
```

Cited by

```
get_cited <- function(link) {
  link %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_elements("#citedby-articles-list .docsum-title") %>%
    html_text2()
}

get_cited(sample_link)

[1] "Household food insecurity risk indices for English neighbourhoods: Measures to support local policy decisions."                           
[2] "Variation of parental feeding practices during the COVID-2019 pandemic: a systematic review."                                             
[3] "Home Food Environment Changes and Dietary Intake during an Adolescent Behavioral Weight Loss Intervention Differ by Food Security Status."
```

DOI info

```
get_doi <- function(link) {
  link %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_elements(".doi .id-link") %>%
    html_text2() %>% 
    first()
} 

[1] "10.1089/chi.2020.0158"
```

EDIT:

```
Putting it all together. 

library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

get_articles <- function(page_number) {
  cat("Scraping index:", page_number, "\n")
  page <- str_c("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=((((((%E2%80%98Food%20Supply%E2%80%99%20(MeSH))%20OR%20%E2%80%98Food%20Storage%E2%80%99%20(MeSH))%20OR%20%E2%80%98Hunger%E2%80%99(MeSH)%20OR%20food%20security%20OR%20food%20insecurity%20OR%20household%20food%20security%20OR%20global%20food%20security)%20OR%20household%20food%20insecurity)))%20AND%20((%E2%80%98Prevalence%E2%80%99%20(MeSH))%20OR%20%E2%80%98Cross-Sectional%20Studies%E2%80%99%20(MeSH)%20OR%20cross-sectional%20study%20OR%20Prevalence%20Studies%20OR%20prevalence%20study%20OR%20Cross-Sectional%20Analyses%20OR%20CrossSectional%20Analysis%20OR%20Cross%20Sectional%20Analysis%20OR%20Cross%20Sectional%20Analyses)&filter=lang.english&filter=lang.portuguese&size=200&page=",
        page_number) %>% read_html()
  
  page %>%
    html_elements(".docsum-content") %>%
    map_dfr(
      ~ tibble(
        title = .x %>%
          html_element(".docsum-title") %>%
          html_text2(),
        authors = .x %>%
          html_element(".full-authors") %>%
          html_text2(),
        PMID = .x %>%
          html_element(".docsum-pmid") %>%
          html_text2(),
        synopsis = .x %>%
          html_element(".full-view-snippet") %>%
          html_text2(),
        link = .x %>%
          html_element(".docsum-title") %>%
          html_attr("href") %>%
          str_c("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov", .)
      )
    )
}

df <- map_dfr(1:21, get_articles)

get_info <- function(link) {
  cat("Scraping:", link, "\n")
  tibble(
    abstract = link %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_elements(".abstract-content.selected") %>%
      html_text2(),
    cited = link %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_elements("#citedby-articles-list .docsum-title") %>%
      html_text2(),
    doi = link %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_elements(".doi .id-link") %>%
      html_text2() %>%
      first()
  )
}

df %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 10) %>% 
  mutate(
    info = map(link, get_info)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(everything()) %>% 
  nest(data = cited)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. Would it be possible to use more functions at the same time (e.g. get_doi(), get_cite(), etc.) in order to create multiple variables for a data frame out of those?

Comment: Just plug these in the `map_chr()` as you did with the code snippet you posted - should work

Comment: Do you mean  `map_chr(link, get_abstract, get_cite, get_doi`?

Comment: @Helena No. Check out my edit and adjust accordingly - this should scrape all 4073 articles available on the site.